# Android: intent.putExtra() changes objects?

Tags: java, android, class, android-intent, hashmap

I want to pass *myObject* to the *NewActivity* class. For this I use the *putExtra()* and *getExtras()* methods from *Intent*. It appears however that the object changes somehow? I'm printing the object both before and after I pass it.

Is this normal? I'm running into problems because I'm using myObject in a HashMap, and since the object in NewActivity is essentially an entirely different object I can't use it as a key anymore.

Passing the object:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, NewActivity.class);
MyClass myObject = new MyClass();
myIntent.putExtra("test", myObject);
System.out.println("OBJECT BEFORE: " + myObject);
```

Retrieving the object:

```
MyClass myObject = (MyClass) getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable("test");
System.out.println("OBJECT AFTER: " + myObject);
```

The (different) prints:

```
I/System.out: OBJECT BEFORE: my.project.MyClass@8fe5ae4
I/System.out: OBJECT AFTER: my.project.MyClass@9f1fb7b
```

Comment: intent.putExtra() changes objects? - sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Serializing and de-serializing does create new objects.

If that's an issue for you because you use it as a key into a `HashMap`, you should implement the `boolean equals(Object other)` and the `int hashCode()` methods in your class.

Check out [Java hashCode()](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_hashCode()) on Wikipedia and [`public int hashCode()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29) in Oracle's documentation to learn how to implement a "hashable" object.

If your object doesn't depend on identity anymore when being used as a key your problem should be solved.

Comment: Thank you, this seems to be the best (and only) solution so far.

Answer (score 1):

change this

getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable()

to

```
getIntent().getSerializableExtra("test")
```

Comment: have you implemented serializable interface in your MyClass ?

Comment: Yeah, otherwise it wouldn't work in the first place.

Comment: ok the thing is the when you pass an object between activity it creates a new object with same values in it  thats why the reference get changed

Comment: So how can I pass the actual object to a new activity?

Comment: one hack that you can do is that you make a class with static object and refer that to the object you want to pass . and fetch that static object  in next activity. but its might be a bad approach as of now i dont think their is another way

Comment: I know there's all kinds of ways to hack myself around this, but it's gonna be a mess when you have many cases like this. There must be a proper way. Anyway I appreciate the help mate.

Comment: Just wanted to let you know I found the solution, it's the answer of this topic. :)

Answer (score -1):

That is how Serializable objects work. 100% basic Java.

They serialize objects into raw data, and then when they're un-serialized, it will create a completely new object of the same type, and set all the values that the old object had onto the new one.

So the object references won't be the same, which is also why a different hashCode is printed out when you call `System.out.println`.

The internal values of the object will be the same.

Comment: Is there any (proper) way to pass the real object to the new activity then?

Comment: No. To pass data directly to a specific Activity, the only choice is to do it via Intent Extra's. If you have more general data, you could perhaps use a Singleton to store the data, and then simply access it in the new Activity. Then they would be the "real objects". But if you really depend on them being the real object references, then something else in your code is most likely wrong.

Answer (score -1):

For passing object one activity to another, Your object class should implement "Serializable".

```
public class MyClass implements Serializable{
// 
}
```

pass data

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, NewActivity.class);
MyClass myObject = new MyClass();
myIntent.putExtra("test", myObject);
```

Retrieve data

```
MyClass myObject = (MyClass) getIntent().getSerializable("test");
```

Hope this will work :)

Comment: That's literally what I'm doing

Comment: Do object change its data ??

Comment: Same data but different object.

Comment: Obviously, it will create a different object. You are not sending it as a reference. The object is simply coping into another memory location.